# How can I draw bars close to each other in matplotlib's bar function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this bar chart, obtained in Seaborn, using `barplot`:

[image: Seaborn picture]

I have the bar chart for the same dataset, obtained by Matplotlib's `bar`:
[image: Matplotlib picture]

Is there a way, a switch, etc. to get the bars in Matplotlib's picture closer, like they are in the Seaborn version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your x data to strings, since `bar` can handle categorical data. Some sample code:

```
plt.bar(['1', '2', '97', '99'], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Output:

[image]